# Overriding the authentication failure handler - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am extending the authentication failure handler and everything is mainly working ok, but for one small problem.

This is my services.yml:

```
  http.utils.class:
    class: Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils
  auth.fail:
    class: Acme\MyBundle\AuthenticationFailure
    arguments:
      - @http_kernel
      - @http.utils.class
      - []
```

I have set this to be used in security.yml:

```
failure_handler: auth.fail
```

This is my Acme\MyBundle\AuthenticationFailure.php:

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AuthenticationFailure extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {

        //do something

    }

}
```

The problem is that the options I've set in security.yml are ignored. I know the third parameter of the _construct method of the class is the $options array, and I've not passed anything in as the third parameter (in services.yml), so I'm guessing this is the problem and a solution could be to just pass the values in. I'm guessing I could also do something like this:

```
arguments:
  - @http_kernel
  - @http.utils.class
  - %security.firewalls.secure_area.form_login%
```

....I've not tested as the problem is this is hard-coding that in services.yml and it isn't ideal as if I changed the name of secure_area it would break. Surely these values are available in a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see you're trying to pass the **login_path** to your authentication failure handler...

... you should inject `@router`, adapt the `__construct` method and generate the url with the **route name** ( *not pattern* ) used by your firewall inside the auth failure handler. then redirect the user there...

```
login_path: your_login_route_name # <- not a pattern like /login
```

this way changing the name of the firewall will not break your application!

---

if you don't even want to break the application when changing the route name you can make this configurable aswell:

**config.yml**

```
parameters:
   login.route_name: my_login_route_name
```

**routing.yml**

```
%login.route_name%:
     pattern: /login
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
    firewalls:
        your_firewall_name:
             failure_handler: auth.fail
             login_path:      %login.route_name%
```

**services.yml**

```
auth.fail:
     arguments:
         - # ...
         - @router
         - %login.route_name%
```

**Acme\MyBundle\AuthenticationFailure**

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

// ...

protected $router;

protected $loginRoute;

public function __construct( 
    /** ... other arguments **/, 
    RouterInterface $router, 
    $loginRoute
) 
{ 
    // ..
    $this->router     = $router;
    $this->loginRoute = $loginRoute;
}

public function onAuthenticationFailure(
    Request $request, 
    AuthenticationException $exception
)
{

    // ...

    return new RedirectResponse( $this->router->generate($this->loginRoute) ); 
}
```

---

**Tip regarding your suggestion**

( ... using something like `%security.firewalls.secure_area.form_login%` )

you cannot access the security configuration directly ( these are not parameters - you can't use `%security.firewall.whatever%` ! ) ...

The the default `$options` passed to `__construct` has to be an array ...

... so you might need to surround your passed parameters by `[]` if those parameters are not an array.

```
arguments:
    - [ %parameter1% , %parameter2% ]
```