# synfony fosuser catch AccountExpiredException

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like catch the AccountExpiredException with fosUser while user login. Actually if user have an expired account he is redirect to login form. I would like change it and give him the possibility to connect. I have a login manager and i don't know where i can catch AccountExpiredException and change action.

EDIT :

I have found where i can change this action , it is in UserChecker class(security/core/user)  ,  but i don't want directly write in this class. I can't find a way to override UserChecker and change checkPreAuth. Some help very appreciate , i'm lost.

EDIT :
i use symfony 2.7 , the only way (ugly way) i found is to commente $user->isAccountNonExpired() like this :

```
 class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
   public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
   {
    if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
        return;
    }

    if (!$user->isAccountNonLocked()) {
        $ex = new LockedException('User account is locked.');
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;
    }

    if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
        $ex = new DisabledException('User account is disabled.');
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;
    }

    if (!$user->isAccountNonExpired()) {

        /*$ex = new AccountExpiredException('User account has expired.');
        $ex->setUser($user);
        throw $ex;*/
    }
}
```

i dont find the good methode to override checkPreAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would like to extend the AuthenticationFailureHandler.
See (just as one reference) the accepted answer here: [Overriding the authentication failure handler - Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545694/overriding-the-authentication-failure-handler-symfony2)

As you did not provide any other information: Depending on the Symfony version you're using you might like to check out the new Guard Authentication on Symfony.

Comment: Symfony version 2.7.3  My class to handle login and registration :  LoginManager implements EventSubscriberInterface.... how can i listen expire exception  event and not redirect to login .

Comment: I have implemented AuthenticationFailureEvent :       public function onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureEvent $event){
        
        print_r($event);
        $response = new RedirectResponse('http://www.goole.fr');
            $response->send();
            die;
        
    } but the event is not fired when account is expired ....

Comment: you'll have to provide more code and config in order to support